# Valor del campo input text viene vacio

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo dos `input type="range"` que me muestra el valor en un `input type="text"` por medio de javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("campo1").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var valor = this.value; // obtiene el valor del campo de entrada "range"
  document.getElementById("campo-1").value = valor; // establece el valor en el campo de entrada de texto
  });
    
  document.getElementById("campo2").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var valor = this.value; // obtiene el valor del campo de entrada "range"
  document.getElementById("campo-2").value = valor; // establece el valor en el campo de entrada de texto
  });
```

```html
<!--Presentación: 0 o 20 puntos--->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-10"> 
<label for="rangeInput">Presentación: 0 o 20 puntos</label>
<input type="range" required  id="campo1" min="0" max="20" value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">  
<input type="text" name="auditoria1" id="campo-1">
</div>
</div>
    
<!--Indagación: 0 o 30 puntos--->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-10"> 
<label for="rangeInput">Indagación: 0 o 30 puntos</label>
<input type="range" required  id="campo2" min="0" max="30" value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">  
<input type="text" name="auditoria2" id="campo-2">
</div>
</div>


La idea es traer el valor del input ranger y llevarlo a la base de datos.
```

ese es el script que muestra el resultado en el input con type id `campo-1`, `campo-2` y en type name `auditoria1`, `auditoria2`

Estoy intentando insertar en la base datos el valor del inputa type name `auditoria2` y `auditoria2`, resulta que viene vacio.
¿Alquen sabe como hago para traer ese dato del input name `auditoria1` y `auditoria2` para insertar en la base de datos?, ya he intentado de todo.
Estoy usando PHP y Mysql

Scrip que inserto los campos a la base de datos

```
$insertar = "insert into colaboradores (id, fecha, inicio, fin, colaborador, referente, temas, objetivo, acciones, auditoria1, auditoria2, auditoria3, auditoria4, resultado) values ('$id', '$fecha' , '$inicio', '$fin', '$colaborador', '$referente' , '$temas' , '$objetivo' , '$acciones', '$auditoria1', '$auditoria2', '$auditoria3', '$auditoria4', '$resultado')";
mysqli_query($conn, $insertar) or die (mysql_error());
```

Todos los campos se insertan bien menos los de auditoria1, auditoria2, etc

Comment: ¿Cómo estás intentando insertar los campos a la base de datos? Adjúntanos el código.

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta y coloque el código de inserción a la base de datos

Comment: Necesitamos que agregues todo el codigo relacionado, el formulario, la lectura de los datos, y el ingreso a la BD... aun falta codigo de esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como no tengo 50 de reputación aun comento por este medio:

creo que cada vez que se mueve la barra del <input type="range" genera un evento y si cada vez que se llama al evento insertas datos en la base de datos entonces una cuantas personas triaran tu pagina web con solo mover el <input type="range" , el input "campo-1" si muestra el numero el problema debe estar en como insertas los datos en la db.